# In what cases linear SVM and LDA are equivalent?

Tags: classification, svm

Lately I've been training some binary classifiers for a school project, and I realized that my linear SVM in most cases gives almost identical AUC scores as my LDA classifier.
I used C=1 for the SVM and automatic shrinkage (using the Ledoit-Wolf lemma) for the LDA.

What circumstances can produce such similar results for two classifier having so little in common?

Answer (score 2):

When you have very strong separation between classes based on your (obviously) strong predictors, many algorithms will end up with similar performance. You may get the same accuracy and AUC using decision trees or forests, neural networks, etc. That this occurs despite vastly different modeling architectures is driven by the separability of the data.

Comment: And even then they won't be 'equivalent'. I'm pretty sure the decision hyperplane won't be the same between the SVM and LDA, unless under some strict conditions. LDA hyperplane is positioned based on class centroids while the SVM hyperplane is based on the support-vectors themselves, which most often are not the totality of the samples (+1).

Answer (score -2):

Since more than 20 years, classifiers are being combined into 'bags' (total classifiers), using summing or voting schemes. It is well-known that very different classifier algorithms can be combined into really well-performing 'total classifiers'. Such a total classifier commonly outperforms all the individual classifiers that are part of it.

This is clear evidence that classifiers perform differently, especially on difficult classification tasks. Classifier choice does matter.

**Reference:**

J. Kittler, M. Hatef, R.P.W. Duin, J. Matas. "On combining classifiers," *IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence*, Volume 20, Issue 3, pp. 226 - 239, 1998.